# How to add data from localStorage into an input box?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass data from an input field on one page to an input field on a second page.

Using localStorage I am able to get the data and then output it as an alert on the target page.

```
<script>      
    function setValue() {
      var parseAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
      localStorage.setItem("amountKey", parseAmount);
   }  

  </script>
```

However, I need the stored data to populate this input field:

```
<input type="number" class="" id="demo2" value="3000"/>
```

My best effort so far is:

```
<script>      
    function getValue() {
        var parseAmount2 = localStorage.getItem("amountKey");

  document.getElementById("demo2").value = parseAmount2;
    }  

  </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are any errors being created? Are you calling the `getValue` function anywhere? Maybe add a button that calls it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items from localStorage are defined as strig, your input is defined as number, try parseInt (and do you invoke **getValue()**?):

```
function getValue() {
  var parseAmount2 = localStorage.getItem("amountKey");
  document.getElementById("demo2").value = parseInt(parseAmount2);
}
getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the content on the page loads, you can load the value into the page.

```
/* modern browsers - will execute code once all elements are loaded onto the client */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    // content is loaded, load the value from storage
    getValue(); // call the function to perform
});

function getValue() {
   var parseAmount2 = localStorage.getItem("amountKey");
    document.getElementById("demo2").value = parseAmount2;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event